# Converting *.tif file into headerless (flat) binary file?

Tags: remote-sensing, file-formats, envi, raster-conversion

I am using NDVI files (value range -1 to +1) created from Landsat CDR images to produce a timeseries in TIMESAT software.

My  .tif file has following characteristics. 
File type  TIFF,Data Type  Double Precision, Byte Order Host (Intel), Interleave BSQ

As per the requirement of TIMESAT, the image should be headerless(flat) binary file, and values can be stored as 8 bit integer(0-255), 16 bit signed integer(-32767 to +32768) or 32 bit real.

Now i need to change my data type into any of these 3 format and .tif file into headerless binary files.

Any idea?

Answer (score 10):

GDAL's [ENVI](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#ENVI) driver can be used to write headerless binary data files. The default data interleave is band sequential (BSQ), but BIP or BIL interleave options can be specified as a creation option.

For example, [to convert](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) a GeoTIFF file `foo.tif` to a headerless file `foo.bin`:

```
gdal_translate -of ENVI foo.tif foo.bin
```

The ASCII file `foo.bin.hdr` will also be created with the header data, but this can be ignored.

Answer (score 5):

In ENVI 5x (the procedure is similar in ENVI 4x or ENVI 5 Classic), use the [File > Save As](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/SavingFiles.html#SaveFiles) menu to save your TIFF to [ENVI format](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/ENVIImageFiles.html) which is a flat binary file. This should default to BSQ, but if it doesn't you can convert using the [Convert Interleave](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/ManageRasterData.html#Convert2) tool. You also get header (.hdr) and pyramid (*.enp) files, but you can delete those.