# open source command line tools on Linux or source code for converting tiff image file to BSQ file

Tags: convert, geotiff-tiff

Let me know homepages related to open source command line tools on Linux or source codes for converting tiff image file to BSQ file.

Comment: What's a 'raw file'? A binary like a BIL/BSQ, ASCII (Text) like ASC/XYZ or CSV data? Please edit your question to define what you mean by a raw image file, what coding language (and API) you're interested in (if known) and preferably what OS you're using (Windows, Linux, Mac...).

Comment: Thank you Michael. It was solved by the previous answer. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112162/how-can-i-convert-tif-file-into-headerless-flat-binary-files

Comment: That answer uses Gdal_Translate which can be found http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html ... GDAL itself can be downloaded in many ways; do you have it installed already? If not, the way to effect download is slightly different depending on OS and what else you may want to do with the GDAL library. Possibly the best way is to download and install QGIS which comes with GDAL/OGR/PROJ.4 and you have the benefit of a fully functional GIS package.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Gdal already have been installed on my PC, Linux. It works on conversion of tiff to bin.